# VSCode Redhat language support for Java's formatter forces max line length

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, redhat

I'm using VS Code IDE for Java project. I install [Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java) for formating code.

settings.json:

```json
{
    "java.configuration.updateBuildConfiguration": "automatic",
    "java.debug.settings.hotCodeReplace": "auto",
    "java.format.settings.url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/styleguide/gh-pages/eclipse-java-google-style.xml",
    "java.format.settings.profile": "GoogleStyle",
}
```

I'm writing a class like that:

```java
public class Foo {
    private int theFirstVariable, theSecondVariable, theThirdVariable, theFourthVariable, theFifthVariable, theSixthVariable;
    Foo(
        int theFirstVariable,
        int theSecondVariable,
        int theThirdVariable,
        int theFourthVariable,
        int theFifthVariable,
        int theSixthVariable
    ) {
        this.theFirstVariable = theFirstVariable;
        this.theSecondVariable = theSecondVariable;
        this.theThirdVariable = theThirdVariable;
        this.theFourthVariable = theFourthVariable;
        this.theFifthVariable = theFifthVariable;
        this.theSixthVariable = theSixthVariable;
    }
}
```

When i format code (Press `Ctrl + s`), it becomes:

```java
public class Foo {
    private int theFirstVariable, theSecondVariable, theThirdVariable, theFourthVariable,
            theFifthVariable, theSixthVariable;

    Foo(int theFirstVariable, int theSecondVariable, int theThirdVariable, int theFourthVariable,
            int theFifthVariable, int theSixthVariable) {
        this.theFirstVariable = theFirstVariable;
        this.theSecondVariable = theSecondVariable;
        this.theThirdVariable = theThirdVariable;
        this.theFourthVariable = theFourthVariable;
        this.theFifthVariable = theFifthVariable;
        this.theSixthVariable = theSixthVariable;
    }
}
```

At the constructor, it seems like the formator was trying to fill every parameters into one line until maximum line length exceeded. Can we keep keep the fommer's format and how to if we can?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to save all your wanted formatting style. but there's optional setting.

Download the GoogleStyle.xml and change the setting:

```
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.join_wrapped_lines" value="false"/>
```

Then in Settings.json:

```
"java.format.settings.url": "<local path to java-google-style.xml>",
```

This won't keep you code as the same as the one when you write it down, but at least the parameters are split into lines. Although not that good:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tried to create custom `eclipse-java-google-style.xml` and modify as @Molly Wang suggested. And I found some modifications that could give the result i want:

```xml
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.continuation_indentation" value="1" />
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.join_wrapped_lines" value="false"/>
```

After formating, the code becomes:

```java
public class Foo {
    private int theFirstVariable, theSecondVariable, theThirdVariable, theFourthVariable, theFifthVariable, theSixthVariable;
    Foo(
        int theFirstVariable,
        int theSecondVariable,
        int theThirdVariable,
        int theFourthVariable,
        int theFifthVariable,
        int theSixthVariable) {
        this.theFirstVariable = theFirstVariable;
        this.theSecondVariable = theSecondVariable;
        this.theThirdVariable = theThirdVariable;
        this.theFourthVariable = theFourthVariable;
        this.theFifthVariable = theFifthVariable;
        this.theSixthVariable = theSixthVariable;
    }
}
```

If you want the constructor's close paren to be in next line, add a blank line like this:

```java
public class Foo {
    private int theFirstVariable, theSecondVariable, theThirdVariable, theFourthVariable,
        theFifthVariable, theSixthVariable;

    Foo(
        int theFirstVariable,
        int theSecondVariable,
        int theThirdVariable,
        int theFourthVariable,
        int theFifthVariable,
        int theSixthVariable

    ) {
        this.theFirstVariable = theFirstVariable;
        this.theSecondVariable = theSecondVariable;
        this.theThirdVariable = theThirdVariable;
        this.theFourthVariable = theFourthVariable;
        this.theFifthVariable = theFifthVariable;
        this.theSixthVariable = theSixthVariable;
    }
}
```